# Xamarin Binding and normal text in a label

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

is there a posibility to have a label, with a "standart" text AND a binding content? this is what i´m looking for:

```
 <Label Text="Hello, this is {Binding name}"/>
```

but this doesnt work. i know, i could make it like this:

```
  <Label Text="Hello, this is "/>
  <Label Text="{Binding name}"/>
```

but i would really like to do it in only one label, because if there's a wordwrap, it doesnt look that well.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it in code, so something like this.

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
get
{
return String.Format("Hello, this is {0}", _name);
}
set
{
_name = value;
RaisePropertyChanged("Name"); //bear in mind this is depended on MVVM framework you are using
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [FormattedText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#formatted-text) property on Label

```
<Label>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="Hello, this is ">
            <Span Text="{Binding name}">
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```